# .NET ConfigurationErrorsException: The element may only appear once in this section

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, web-config, asp.net-2.0

```
 <LoginManagersSection>
   <LoginManagers>
     <SiteLoginManagers site="*">
       <LoginManager businessObject="DealerTraining" regex="\/Training.*\.html"  />
       <LoginManager  businessObject="DealerSupport" regex="\/DealerSupport.*\.html"  />
       <LoginManager  businessObject="Regular" regex="\/(?!WebTrendsJS).*\.html"  />
     </SiteLoginManagers>
     <SiteLoginManagers site="xrn">
       <LoginManager  businessObject="DealerTraining" regex="\/Training.*\.html"  />
       <LoginManager  businessObject="DealerSupport" regex="\/DealerSupport.*\.html"  />
       <LoginManager businessObject="XrnDealer" regex="\/Dealer.*\.html"  />
       <LoginManager businessObject="Regular" regex="\//(?!JS).*\.html"  />
     </SiteLoginManagers>
   </LoginManagers>
 </LoginManagersSection>
```

We have multiple web sites, and those sites needs different `LoginManager` instances. Same login manager for any given regex rule may be overwritten in a different site.

We have a custom section in our configuration files and I was trying to add one more SiteLoginManagers node with a different key.

*The problem:* I am getting

> ConfigurationErrorsException: The element `<SiteLoginManagers>` may only appear once in this section.

Is it possible to do that ?

We are using .NET 2.0.

Comment: nice edit @Jeff Yates thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a custom `IConfigurationSectionHandler` (or [`ConfigurationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx)) implementation to handle multiple sections. More details can be found [here on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx) and in [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/374c2ac5-1505-450e-9de7-e5c15586a754).